# selenium "FirefoxWebElement" object is not iterable

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

My code is instagram get all followers.
Error code line 69: TypeError: "FirefoxWebElement" is not iterable. It's my code;

```
lenOfPage = browser.execute_script(jscommand)
match = False
while(match==False):
lastCount = lenOfPage
time.sleep(1)
lenOfPage = browser.execute_script(jscommand)
if lastCount == lenOfPage:
    match = True
time.sleep(5)
followersList = []
followers = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/ul/div/li[243]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]")
for follower in followers:
   followersList.append(follower.text)


with open("followers.txt","w",encoding = "UTF-8") as file:
    for follower in followersList:
       file.write(follower + "\n")
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting your error when you iterate over `followers` which is an element. You can't iterate over Selenium elements.

Speaking from personal experience, it's easier just to scroll through the followers popup and load all the `li` elements from the page and then grab the `.text` of the whole followers popup. That string will return the username, account name, and a status (following/follow/requested). Then you can do some post processing to get rid of the whatever info you don't want.

Here's what I mean:

```
actions = ActionChains(browser)
follower_count = browser.find_element_by_xpath('some_xpath_here') #find the number of followers the user has
my_followers_count = int(follower_count.text) #grab the .txt value of it
followers = browser.find_element_by_xpath('xpath_for_popup').click() #find and click the followers popup menu
print("follower list opened")

for i in range(follower_count): #loop to scroll the popup
    actions.send_keys(Keys.DOWN).perform()
print("Followers scan complete: " + str(my_followers_count) + " followers scanned")

my_followers_element = browser.find_element_by_class_name('classname') #grab all followers inside popup
my_followers = my_followers_element.text #store into multiline string
```

This solution will require a couple of imports

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

Now if you wanted to loop, you could iterate over `my_followers` and your output would look something like this

```
"""username1
account name
following
username2
account name2
requested"""
```